# Convert Azure Table storage entities to JSON

Tags: php, json, azure, azure-table-storage

Is there a way to convert Azure Table storage entities to JSON?

The Azure Entity object in PHP has a lot of meta data. Is there a good way to clean it, and return a JSON object with only the relevant data.

The Entity object prints something like this

```
WindowsAzure\Table\Models\Entity Object
        (
            [_etag:WindowsAzure\Table\Models\Entity:private] => W/"datetime'2013-10-07T04%3A19%3A37.0155205Z'"
            [_properties:WindowsAzure\Table\Models\Entity:private] => Array
                (
                    [PartitionKey] => WindowsAzure\Table\Models\Property Object
                        (
                            [_edmType:WindowsAzure\Table\Models\Property:private] => 
                            [_value:WindowsAzure\Table\Models\Property:private] => weather
                        )

                    [RowKey] => WindowsAzure\Table\Models\Property Object
                        (
                            [_edmType:WindowsAzure\Table\Models\Property:private] => 
                            [_value:WindowsAzure\Table\Models\Property:private] => 0d625293-ef40-492b-bf07-d2889597a8f4
                        )

                    [Timestamp] => WindowsAzure\Table\Models\Property Object
                        (
                            [_edmType:WindowsAzure\Table\Models\Property:private] => Edm.DateTime
                            [_value:WindowsAzure\Table\Models\Property:private] => DateTime Object
                                (
                                    [date] => 2013-10-07 04:19:37
                                    [timezone_type] => 3
                                    [timezone] => UTC
                                )

                        )

                    [type] => WindowsAzure\Table\Models\Property Object
                        (
                            [_edmType:WindowsAzure\Table\Models\Property:private] => Edm.Int32
                            [_value:WindowsAzure\Table\Models\Property:private] => 1
                        )

                    [city] => WindowsAzure\Table\Models\Property Object
                        (
                            [_edmType:WindowsAzure\Table\Models\Property:private] => 
                            [_value:WindowsAzure\Table\Models\Property:private] => Pune
                        )


                    [temperature] => WindowsAzure\Table\Models\Property Object
                        (
                            [_edmType:WindowsAzure\Table\Models\Property:private] => Edm.Int32
                            [_value:WindowsAzure\Table\Models\Property:private] => 34.7
                        )

                    [localTime] => WindowsAzure\Table\Models\Property Object
                        (
                            [_edmType:WindowsAzure\Table\Models\Property:private] => 
                            [_value:WindowsAzure\Table\Models\Property:private] => 2013-10-07T04:19:31.724Z
                        )

                )

        )
```

I would like to have a clean JSON output something like this

```
{
   PartitionKey:"weather",
   RowKey: "0d625293-ef40-492b-bf07-d2889597a8f4",
   Timestamp: "2013-10-07 04:19:37"
   type: 1,
   city: "Pune",
   tempterature: 34.7
   localTime: "2013-10-07T04:19:31.724Z"
}
```

I have implemented a loop to achieve this. I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it.

```
$entities = $result->getEntities();
        $jsonArray = array();

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($entities); $i++) {
            $arr = $entities[$i]->getProperties();
            $tempArr = array();
            foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
                if(gettype($entities[$i]->getPropertyValue($key)) != 'object'){

                    $tempArr[$key] = (string)$entities[$i]->getPropertyValue($key);                 }
                else
                {

                    $tempArr[$key] = serialize($entities[$i]->getPropertyValue($key));
                }
            }
            array_push($jsonArray, $tempArr);
        }
        echo json_encode($jsonArray);
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `The Azure Entity object in PHP has a lot of meta data`. Can you explain? Furthermore, since Azure Table Storage is schema-less by design there are no null attributes.

Comment: he means the Azure Entity object has a lot of information that is 'beyond' the expected data. And that object is not well documented such that an outsider cannot make reasonable sense of it without asking questions that make him look foolish to those with insider knowledge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have answered your own question :). I would have recommended same approach i.e. loop over properties array and create a JSON representation out of it.

One thing I do want to mention is that currently JSON is not natively supported in Windows Azure Tables but it is coming soon (it was demonstrated in //Build conference in July). When that happens, you would be able to directly request table storage to return you the data in JSON format and not go through this conversion exercise. Till that time, I think this would be the approach you would need to follow.

Answer (score 3):

Now that Windows Azure table storage services supports JSON, you can do this a bit more easily. You can see the announcement here: Windows Azure Storage Release - Introducing CORS, JSON, Minute Metrics, and More.

I have a simple example that illustrates a similar scenario here: http://www.contentmaster.com/azure/windows-azure-table-storage-json/

The example shows how to upload and download directly from a Windows Azure table using client-side JavaScript.